# How to validate disabled textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a one textbox and two radio buttons yes and no. When I click yes the textbox will become enable and when I click no textbox will become disable. Now my question is when I click yes the textbox should validate like please enter the amount. If I click no it should not ask for validation how can I achieve this? how to test whether the textbox is enable or not? and based on that javascript work.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML/JS in your message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable textbox when radio button is click using onchange event and check in validate method whether textbox is disabled or not.

```js
function disableTextbox(){
    if(document.myform.disableMe.value=="yes"){
       document.getElementById('amount').disabled=true;
       alert("Dont validate");
    }else if(document.myform.disableMe.value=="no"){
        document.getElementById('amount').disabled=false;
       
        alert("Validate");
    }
}

function validate(){
    var amt=document.getElementById('amount');
     if(!amt.disabled && amt.value==""){
          alert("Please enter some value");
          return false;
     }else{
       
          alert("Success");
          
     }
     
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="#">
<input type="text" id="amount">
  <input type="radio" name="disableMe" onchange="disableTextbox()" value="yes">
  <input type="radio" name="disableMe" onchange="disableTextbox();" value="no">
    
  
  <button onclick="validate();">Validate</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Exactly what I needed and specially the button one

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
var elm=document.getElementById("yourInputFieldId");
if (elm.disabled==false) {
    //add your required filed validation code here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validate(){
  var inp=document.getElementById('amount');
  inp.disabled=false;
  if (inp.value.length==0)
    alert("Please enter the amount!");
 } 
 function disable_inp(){
  var inp=document.getElementById('amount');
  inp.disabled=true;
 } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <form>
  <input type='radio' name='a' onchange='validate();' value='yes' />
  <input type='radio' name='a' onchange='disable_inp();'value='no' />
  <input type='text' name='amount' id='amount' />
 </form>
</div></body>
</html>
```